# How to convert string to byte and the GB in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field which store messages and I want to get how many Gb's this message is consuming.
For example message: "Hi how are you?" So I want to convert this string in Gb's

Comment: You mean `length()`, or `lengthb()`, of individual values? Or the total (sum) over all values? Or the size of the table, or LOB segment if it's stored as a LOB?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you want the size of that one string or do you want the total size of the all the values in a column of a table (note: tables have columns and not fields) or do you want the total size of the table containing those values? Or do you have an Object data type and one of the attributes of the object has the message and you want to know something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of the string in gigabytes, you can use:

```
SELECT LENGTHB( 'Hi how are you?' ) / POWER( 2, 30 ) AS size_in_gigabytes
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | SIZE_IN_GIGABYTES |
> | --- |
> | .000000013969838619232177734375 |